# center a div within organized column system

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation, grid-layout

I am creating a web page and wanted to use a system similar to foundations/ bootstrap with defined columns and rows. I am happy with what I have so far, however I am not sure how I can center a column within a row, while still using a defined grid system. 
I know usually the html is formatted like this:

```
 <div class="column column-6 center">
```

http://codepen.io/Kiwimoose/pen/dpvEqO

Is what I have so far, 
I am just not sure how the "center" tag is usually formatted in foundations. I would like to have the column in the second row centered, as well as others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK, you just have to change the order in CSS:

```
.column {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.center {
    margin:auto;
    float:none;
}
```

Style .center class after . column class and it will work. 
BTW, it is a good idea to clean up your code a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much!  

I had no idea order actually mattered in css.   
This makes things so much simpler. 

Aw man,   I thought my code as it was, was pretty clean. Do I need more comments? or is it just the way it's tabbed out? or the general order?   
Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem :). Yes, order matters in CSS, if you style the same element/class in two different places, the second rule will overwrite the first one (only properties that are doubled). So it is a good idea to add general styles (e.g. .column class) at the top of your CSS file, so you can then overwrite them (e.g. .center class). This CSS feature is very, very useful :). When it comes to other aspects of code quality, keep spacing consistent, one line between rules and each property in separate line (you have some empty line inside rules). You have enough comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div align="center">
```

And then you can customize it in the css that you're doing

Answer (score 0):

In Zurb foundation you can use "**-offset-**" and "end" class names,
for example

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="large-6 large-offset-3 end columns">6 centered</div>
</div>
```

[docs here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html)

Comment: Yea I typically work in foundations, however in this case I am not. 
I want to learn the systems of how something like foundations works.
I know there are tons of zurb foundation resources on how it works, but it never seems to cover the css aspect of it. And that is what I need to get better at.

Answer (score 0):

to center properly (with no headaches) with Twitter Bootstrap you can simply set empty divs as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
       centered div in all resolutions
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use offset too